# jqGrid: dropdown selectors in Add Record dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqgrid, webforms

I have a jqGrid with a couple fields that dynamically populate dropdown boxes in the filterToolbar.  I would like those same results to show in the "Add Record" dialog, giving the Product and Environment fields a dropdown selector instead of a text input field.  As you can see, I'm trying to do this in the beforeShowForm event.  Is that the proper place to do it?  It would be nice to set the value to the previously defined prodValues and envValues vars, but I can make an ajax request again if necessary (I have already tried and failed that too).

As is, the code still produces the form with text input for both the Product and Environment fields.  How can I change them to selectors?

```
$(function () {
            var grid = $("#PSGrid");

            var prodValues = $.ajax({
                url: "jqGridHandler.ashx?oper=pVals",
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {

                }
            }).responseText;

            var envValues = $.ajax({
                url: "jqGridHandler.ashx?oper=eVals",
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {

                }
            }).responseText;

            var lastsel = -1;

            // build the grid
            grid.jqGrid({
                url: 'jqGridHandler.ashx',
                editurl: 'jqGridEditor.ashx',
                datatype: 'json',
                height: 550,
                width: 'auto',
                colNames: ['ID', 'Product', 'Environment', 'Hostname', 'IP', 'Description', 'Type', 'Ports Used'],
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'ID', index: 'ID', width: 50, sortable: true, hidden: false, editable: false, key: true },
                    {
                        name: 'Product', index: 'Product', width: 125, sortable: true, editable: true,
                        stype: 'select', searchoptions: { value: prodValues, sopt: ['eq'] }
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Environment', index: 'Environment', width: 100, sortable: true, editable: true,
                        stype: 'select', searchoptions: { value: envValues, sopt: ['eq'] }
                    },
                    { name: 'Hostname', index: 'Hostname', width: 200, sortable: true, editable: true },
                    { name: 'IP', index: 'IP', width: 125, sortable: false, editable: true },
                    { name: 'Description', index: 'Description', width: 200, sortable: true, editable: true },
                    { name: 'Type', index: 'Type', width: 75, sortable: true, editable: true },
                    { name: 'Ports Used', index: 'Ports Used', width: 80, sortable: false, editable: true }
                ],
                rowNum: 1000,    // hack to show everything; there's probably a better property to use than this
                pager: '#PSGridPager',
                sortname: 'ID',
                pgbuttons: false,
                pgtext: null,
                viewrecords: false,
                sortorder: 'asc',
                ignoreCase: true,
                caption: 'Click a row to edit.  [Enter] to save, [Esc] to cancel.',
                loadonce: true,
                onSelectRow: function (id) {
                    if (id && id !== lastsel) {
                        grid.jqGrid('restoreRow', lastsel);
                        grid.jqGrid('editRow', id, true);
                        lastsel = id;
                    }
                }
            });

            grid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: true, defaultSearch: "cn" });
            grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#PSGridPager', { edit: false, add: true, del: true, search: false, refresh: true, paging: false },
                { /* edit options */ },
                { /* add options */
                    closeOnEscape: true,
                    width: 400,
                    beforeShowForm: function (formid) {
                        $(this).setColProp('Product', { editoptions: { value: prodValues } });
                        $(this).setColProp('Environment', { editoptions: { value: envValues } });
                    }
                });
            grid.jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#PSGridPager', {
                caption: "Export to Excel",
                onClickButton: function () {
                    grid.jqGrid('excelExport', { url: "jqGridHandler.ashx" });
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure it as a select in the colModel:

```
formatter:'select', edittype:"select", editoptions:{ value: prodValues }
```

and then remove your beforeShowForm code.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I knew it had to be a simple solution but I don't know how many forum threads and stackoverflow questions I read and still couldn't find it.